# How do I use long Decimal Numbers in my input fields? Currently it crashes due to an improperly formatted string?

Tags: android

num1 and num2 are input values that need to have long decimal points but when it parses the string the decimal gets stripped and it crashes. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button addBuyInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBuyInButton);
        addBuyInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText feeNumEditText = findViewById(R.id.feeNumEditText);
                EditText buyInNumEditText = 
findViewById(R.id.buyInNumEditText);
                TextView targetTextView = findViewById(R.id.targetTextView);
```

> Blockquote right around here is where I run into problems...

```
                int num1 = 
Integer.parseInt(feeNumEditText.getText().toString());
                int num2 = 
Integer.parseInt(buyInNumEditText.getText().toString());
                int num3 = 3;
                int num4 = 100;
                int num5 = num1 + num3;
                int num6 = num5 / num4;
                int num7 = num6 * num2;
                int num8 = num7 + num2;

                targetTextView.setText(num8 + "");


            }
        });


    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to use float and DecimalFormat to get desired effect.

```
            String str2 = buyInNumEditText.getText().toString();

            float num1 = Float.parseFloat(str1);
            float num2 = Float.parseFloat(str2);

            float num3 = 3;
            float num4 = 100;
            float num5 = num1 + num3;
            float num6 = num5 / num4;
            float num7 = num6 * num2;
            float num8 = num7 + num2;


            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.########");
            String num9 = formatter.format(num8);
```